# Java - Method that has its Class as the return type?

Tags: java, oop

I am really confused about this code which I am suppose to complete. Here is a snippet of it:

```
public class PuzzleStateSimple implements PuzzleState {

  public PuzzleState moveUp() {
     return null;
  }

  public int[] getStateArray() {

  }

}
```

I don't understand what is going on here. Am I suppose to return the class itself? Or do I constuct a new `PuzzleStateSimple`object and return that? This class does not look like it was designed in the Singleton pattern.

Here is a snippet of a test case which uses this class:

```
public void testMoveUp(){
    // 2 8 3    2 0 3   
    // 1 0 4 -> 1 8 4
    // 7 6 5    7 6 5
    PuzzleState start = createPuzzleState(puzzleCenterPosition.clone()) ;
    PuzzleState goal = createPuzzleState(puzzleFirstRowMiddlePosition2.clone()) ; // note: 2 puzzles of that kind, 2nd one is it

    PuzzleState result = start.moveUp();
    assertTrue("Expected" + printPuzzle(goal.getStateArray()) + ", computed: " + printPuzzle(result.getStateArray()), 
                goal.isEqual(result));
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question you have to answer: is this a **factory method** (used in method chaining) or is PuzzleState an **immutable type**? Google is your friend there, and I wouldn't read any answers until you figure that out, as the people posting answers are going to assume one when the other might be true.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I don't think this class is a factory method. I do not think PuzzleState is an immutable type as there is another method called 'int[] getStateArray'. So I think the author does not intend for this PuzzleState data type to be immutable.

Comment: Well, the only reasons to return your own type from a method like that are generally for factory/chaining methods or for immutable types. It's probably one or the other, and the answer to the question depends on which one it is. There isn't just one right answer here, and it all depends what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Actually now that I think about it, factory/chaining might be the correct intention. I am suppose to implement a Breadth first search to solve this puzzle. So this might be for that purpose.

Comment: Alright, I think it is best to return the current instance of the class instead of making a new instance since using BFS or A* algorithm will require ample use of move.

Comment: @Renren29 But that really depends on the semantics of that `getStateArray` method. For example, if you read the javadoc for [List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()), it _guarantees_ that modifying array will not affect the state of the list - its purpose is to allow the convenience of processing the list using algorithms written to processing an array.

Comment: @Renren29 Furthermore, the line `PuzzleState result = start.moveUp();` in the test case tells me that `PuzzleState` is meant to be immutable, since if it were not, they would not assign the return value to a variable. They might as well write `start.moveUp(); PuzzleState result = start;`, which make no sense. Factory methods return their enclosing object in order to facilitate constructions such as `new StringBuilder().append("My name is ").append(name).append(".")`, or `.

Comment: @AJMansfield Thanks, so if I were to use this in some kind of algorithm, then I would be creating new instances everytime I call move?

Comment: @Renren29 Yes, it would.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60644/discussion-between-renren29-and-ajmansfield).

Answer (score 2):

Non-static methods that return an instance of the class usually return `this` after doing some manipulation of its state. Their purpose is to allow chaining of calls, such as :

```
PuzzleState obj = new PuzzleState();
obj.moveUp().moveRight().moveUp();
```

Other possible use of such methods is to return a copy of the instance for which they are called.

Finally, there are factory methods, that are usually static, and return a new instance of the class. However, factory methods are sometimes declared in a separate factory class, and not in the same class of the instances they produce.

Comment: Might also want to consider immutable types returning new instances.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are correct. At first I thought that only static methods would return new instances, but non-static methods such a clone() can return a new instance too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public PuzzleState moveUp() {
     return null;
  }
```

in this signature it expects `PuzzleState` type of instance in return (not an instance of `Class` type), looking at the naming it seems that method needs to perocess something change instance's internal state and return same instance back i.e. `return this;`

Answer (score 0):

If this should be an immutable object:

```
public class PuzzleStateSimple implements PuzzleState {

    final public int x;
    final public int y;

    public PuzzleStateSimple(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public PuzzleState moveUp() {
        return new PuzzleStateSimple(x, y-1);
    }

}
```

This allows method chaining: `PuzzleState newState = currentState.moveUp().moveUp();`

Comment: This code would not compile, plus it's not cool to do someone's homework for them.

Comment: @KevinWorkman First: I do not care that this is a homework or not. Second: this is compilable (if PuzzleState exists, of course).

Comment: @DávidHorváth Generally we try not to dump full-code solutions on homework assignments, as it takes away the process of problem solving, which is the real lesson trying to be taught here. You've just edited your code so that it would compile, but the behavior it would exhibit is not correct.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Okay, after any changes not compiled. I corrected the code.

Comment: @DávidHorváth Like I said, this code would still not exhibit the correct behavior. This is another reason not to post full code solutions- they're often wrong.

Comment: @KevinWorkman You are right. But, I did not want to post an instant code, but a technique.